# HTTP access to file system on EC2

Tags: tomcat, grails, amazon-web-services

Maybe I am going about this all wrong (I am new to server programming), in which case please let me know.

I have a grails app (2.1.1) running on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk with Tomcat 6, and I have set up restful api's to send JSON's to a client which include URL's to image files.  I have ssh'd into the server to place the images in the appropriate directories.  Note that these are dynamic images to be added to and removed by users, as opposed to static system images.

But when the client tries to connect to the image URL's the server responds with 404 errors.

Am I correct in assuming that because I get a 404 error (instead of connection refused, etc) that it is not a security group issue?

Am I getting a 404 error because . . .

1. the URL is not correct somehow,
2. my Amazon settings are somehow lacking,
3. my Tomcat settings are somehow lacking,
4. or my application is somehow denying the connection?

That is, why am I able to access "http://myenvironment.elasticbeanstalk.com//login"

but not "http://myenvironment.elasticbeanstalk.com//media/images/myImage.jpg"

or "http://myenvironment.elasticbeanstalk.com/media/images/myImage.jpg"

I know that isn't much detail to go on, but I feel like my real problem is a high-level understanding of the issue.

Basically, what is it that controls permission to access the filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using grails resources Plugin? By default it's enable and will map every thing under `/images/*` to the url path `/static`.

So by default, if you want to get an image you should target:

```
http://localhost:8080/project-name/static/images/grails_logo.png
```

This is configured in **ResourcesGrailsPlugin.groovy**:

```
static DEFAULT_URI_PREFIX = 'static'
static DEFAULT_ADHOC_PATTERNS = ["/images/*", "*.css", "*.js"].asImmutable()
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps.  I see now that it is a grails configuration issue.  I am using the plugin 'resources 1.1.6' but don't have a 'ResourcesGrailsPlugin.groovy' file.  I could create one I suppose, but it seems like that is designed for static images.  Is this still a good answer for user-generated dynamic images?  (I have edited my question to add that detail.)